# how to make login page using parse?

Tags: android, parsing, authentication

In this code I want to enter `11111` into username edit text and parse into password edit text to take me to menu Screen activity but it gives me the error:

```
Invalid user name or password
```

I don't know what is the problem ,  any help??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView username, password;
EditText user, pass;
Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userId);
    password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Parse.initialize(this, "Zf7O5nnDyYOFitPV4smTmcICNyX2D1zAxmNxBtAX",
            "OjetvEJYKH27lfiQ0tVgbqyXlDTIWrwuN7TqnnPw");
    ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("SUPERVISOR");
    parseObject.put("Supervisor_Name", "rrr");
    parseObject.put("Supervisor_ID", 11111);
    parseObject.put("Supervisor_Password", "parse");
    parseObject.put("Supervisor_Email", "parser.12@hotmail.com");
    parseObject.put("Supervisor_Phone", 845625487);
    parseObject.saveInBackground();

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String u=user.getText().toString();
            String p=user.getText().toString();

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
                    .getQuery("SUPERVISOR");
            query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_ID", u);
            query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_Password", p);
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (parseObject != null) {

                        // Go to the menu screen
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                MenuScreen.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Invalid user name or password",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: please explain the Parse, ParseObject & ParseQuery classes.

Comment: Where to explain them do we have to do new class for them?

Comment: Why not use the predefined user class and Parse.initialize should go in an Application subclass. Looks as if you need to follow their tutorials but maybe you know what you are doing..

Comment: can you give me these tutorials ?

Answer (score 1):

here is your fault:---

```
        String u=user.getText().toString();
        String p=user.getText().toString();
```

you should write:---

```
        String u=user.getText().toString();
        String p=pass.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Is there another solution ؟